# Best O(n) algorithm to find often appearing numbers?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This is a example. Each number is a value
in the range between [0..k]. A number x is said to appear often in A if at least 1/3 of the numbers
in the array are equal to x.

What would be an O(n) algorithm finding the often appearing numbers for the
case when k is orders of magnitude larger than n?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a [hash map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), i.e. a hash-based mapping (dictionary) from integers to integers? Then just iterate over your input array and compute the counters. In imperative pseudo-code:

```
const int often = ceiling(n/3);
hashmap m;

for int i = 1 to n do {
    if m.contains(A[i])
       m[A[i]] += 1;
    else 
       m[A[i]] = 1;

    if m[A[i]] >= often
        // A[i] is appearing often
        // print it or store it in the result set, etc.
}
```

This is `O(n)` in terms of time (expected) and space.